# How do I create a Live tile with a back background image using ShellTileSchedule?

Tags: windows-phone-7

I'd like to create a Live tile for WP7. aka Mango, that has a front and a back using ShellTileSchedule API. How can I do this?

Answer (score 1):

http://windowsphonegeek.com/news/mango-live-tile-use-a-picture-in-the-isolatedstorage-as-a-background-for-your-tile

or this is maybe even better:

http://www.diaryofaninja.com/blog/2011/04/03/windows-phone-7-live-tile-schedules-ndash-executing-instant-live-tile-updates